# ANSIBLE How to relative dict items to task results at loop?

Tags: ansible, openvz

Need to register results from loop (`task #1`) and check when `command.results` `stderr` is not empty(`task #2`) relatively to loop items, so I can use this condition at new tasks.

The problem is that:

`when` condition from `task #2` doesn't work cause I can't understand how to divide `command.results` relatively to loop items.

Is there solution to work around?

```
---
- name: "CHECK IF EXIST OPENVZ CONTAINER"
  hosts: "projectname-OPENVZHOSTS"
  gather_facts: yes
  remote_user: root
  vars:
    openvz_check:              "yes"
    openvz_instances:
      opwnvz_instance_1:  
        vmid:                  "119"
      opwnvz_instance_2:  
        vmid:                  "118"

  tasks:

  - name: "Ping my hosts"
    ping:


  - name: "1. Register exist containers"
    shell: echo $(vzlist -a {{ item.value.vmid }})
    register: command
    when: openvz_check == "yes"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', openvz_instances) }}"
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: "2. Create variable from command"
    debug: msg="{{ command.results | map(attribute='stderr_lines') | list  }}"
    when: 
      - openvz_check == "yes" 
      - command.results | map(attribute='stderr') | list != "" 
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', openvz_instances) }}"
    ignore_errors: yes

  - debug: msg="{{ command.results | map(attribute='stderr_lines') |list  }}"
```

Debug of `command.results | map(attribute='stderr') | list`:

```
ok: [projectname-OPENVZHOST-S1] => {
    "msg": [
        [], 
        []
    ]
}
```

Please get advice or solution as you see. Or what I need to research.

Regards

PS: have an idea to create folder and then check if it exist or not exist, but have no idea how to relation dict to results

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the *length* filter.

```
- command.results | map(attribute='stderr') | list | length != 0
```

Or even better, just access stderr directly.

```
- command.stderr != ""
```

Full playbook I used is here:

```
---

- name: test playbook
  hosts: all
  vars:
    my_list_var: []
  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "list is empty"
      when:
        - my_list_var | list | length == 0
    - name: ls command
      command: "ls -l /tmp"
      register: result
    - name: debug 2
      debug:
        msg: "no errors"
      when: result.stderr == ""
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work: at first option command.results in any way has length biger 0 cause consist off two empty fields, at second option get error: `'dict object' has no attribute 'stderr' `

Comment: Interesting.  I tested these and didn't have those issues. What version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: Thanks, i'm using 2.6.5. version. Is there possibility to see your testing playbook?

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation and couldn't access my work computer which contained the playbook.  I'm running Ansible 2.7.0.  I updated my answer with the full playbook I used for testing.  You can change the "==" to "!=" for your case.